# How to implement Interactive user guides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, user-interface, user-experience

I'm trying to build an interactive user guide for an application. Basically when its the users first time using the application they will be offered a tour of the site. It'll be pretty much done with a series of modal pop up boxes and focusing on elements.

My problem is i can't find a way to get control of the cursor to move it to certain locations of the page, is there a way to achieve this with JS, Jquery or CSS? Or is there any plugins available?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to move the client's mouse. Maybe you can just  use an image of a cursor and move that to show the user what to do.

Comment: hadn't thought of that! Good idea I'll try it out thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [Bootstrap Tour](http://bootstraptour.com/) or [Joyride Plugin](http://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin)